# Decision tree in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, decision-tree

I am new to machine learning in R. This is my data set:

```
channels <- sample(c("AFFILIATE","DIRECT","DISPLAY"),100,T)
booking <- sample(c("N","Y"),100,T)
placements <- sample(c("R","L","TR","TL"),100,T)
site <- sample(c("www.google.com","www.yahoo.com"),100,T)
campaigns <- sample(c("camp1","camp2","camp3"),100,T)
data <- data.frame(channels,campaigns,site,placements,booking)
```

I want to figure out which combination has higher booking probability. I have used the following R code to compute a decision tree:

```
tree <- rpart(booking~channels+campaigns+site+placements,data=data,method="class")
```

It generates one output, but not in the proper order (I want a tree where the order should be channels → campaigns → site → placements → booking). Also, it only gives two leaf nodes for each parent node, but I want to generate a tree where there will be more than two leaf nodes for each parent node. Are there any advanced methods which can fulfill the requirements?
Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Standard decision trees do not put any constraints on the order of the features except how well they discriminate. So my guess is you wont find any ready implementations to enforce order as you describe (maybe someone else has other suggetions?). If you want the strict order then you can code it yourself. Look in literature how to calculate gini/gain criterion for splitting.

Also most of the implementations that I am aware of implement binary splits, meaning that each parent has two children. What you want is called a "multiway" split.

I hope that this helps.